# I can't export from SQL Server 2014 Express to Access 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014-express

I have a database called `My Travel Project` which I am trying to export to an Access database called `Travel Project Imported`.

I right clicked on the My Travel Project database in SQL Server and chose export.

When the wizard opened I chose `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server` as a data source but I am not sure if this is the correct option to choose and chose Windows authentication.

I was then asked to choose a destination. I tried `Microsoft Access(Microsoft Jet Database Engine)` and put in Travel Project Imported as the file name of the Access database.

When I clicked next I got an error message saying

> The Operation could not be completed

[image].

How can I export this correctly? Thank you

Comment: I'd try the other direction.  Start from access and import from sql-server.  In fact, a linked table might also be appropriate.

Comment: I found out what was wrong with my Export method above. The Access Database that I was using had a 2007-2015 file extension .accdb but the Jet engine only recognises the 2002-2003 ext .mdb

Comment: I had to convert the original DB to .mdb and then Exported it no problem. After exporting i then checked the .mdb file and everything was correct so I converted it back to .accdb.